# Have event handler function create persistant PYQT4 object

Tags: python, forms, events, pyqt4

I am trying to have a window popup after a patch is clicked. I have the event properly matched up and the window flashing on the screen, but it closes immediately after the event function concludes. I want the window to persist. How can i have a event handler function create something persistent?

The class that is the window is below

```
class pickwindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(250, 150)
        self.move(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Selected SubChannel')
        self.l = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        text1 = QtGui.QLabel('Please select 1 or more Subchannel')
        self.chanlist = QtGui.QLabel('')
```

The pick event handler is the following code snip :

```
def onpick(event):
    mouseevent = event.mouseevent
    artist = event.artist
    chanselect = pickwindow()
    chanselect.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window is being garbage-collected when the handler returns, because you are not keeping a reference to it.

Based on your example code, it looks like `pickwindow` should be a [`QDialog`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html):

```
class pickwindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        ...
```

This will allow the window to be opened with [`exec`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#exec), which will block until the user closes it:

```
def onpick(event):
    ...
    chanselect = pickwindow()
    chanselect.exec_()
```

Ideally, the dialog would also have OK/Cancel buttons with their `clicked` signals connected to the dialog's [`accept()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#accept) and [`reject()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#reject) slots. This would then allow you to do this:

```
    if chanselect.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
         # do stuff with selected channel...
    else:
         # user cancelled...
```

**EDIT**:

If you don't want the dialog to block, then give it a parent, and open it with `show`. It would probably be best if `onpick` was a method of the main window, so you could do this:

```
def onpick(self, event):
    ...
    chanselect = pickwindow(self)
    chanselect.show()
```

Comment: This would work but I need to interact with another widget and the dialog freezes you out until the dialog completes. Is there away around that limitation

Comment: @TheCodeNovice. I have updated my answer with an alternative solution.